# Flattening dict/list object - Python vs Sql?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a bit of dict/list values- typically I would store as json and flatten via SQL - but wondering if anyone has any perspective on using python? Just in general the most efficient way to get this data in one row, where the values for dimensions & metricHeaderEntries are columns and the respective row values fall in line under them

BTW this is an example Google Analytics API Export , so may help others. The goal would be to get all the values for Dimension & Metric on one row.

```
{
    "reports": [
        {
            "columnHeader": {
                "dimensions": [
                    "DimA",
                    "DimAB",
                    "DimAC",
                    "DimAD",
                    "DimAE"
                ],
                "metricHeader": {
                    "metricHeaderEntries": [
                        {
                            "name": "METRICAB",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "METRICABAC",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "METRICABACD",
                            "type": "INTEGER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "METRICABADCE",
                            "type": "VARCHAR"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "METRICABADEEW",
                            "type": "FLOAT"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "METRICABADEEFG",
                            "type": "FLOAT"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "data": {
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "(test)",
                            "2019022",
                            "(not set)",
                            "d",
                            "/search"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "0",
                                    "1",
                                    "1",
                                    "100000.0",
                                    "61.0",
                                    "16.0"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "dimensions": [
                            "(test)",
                            "20190222",
                            "(not set)",
                            "asdf",
                            "/adf"
                        ],
                        "metrics": [
                            {
                                "values": [
                                    "30",
                                    "133",
                                    "31",
                                    "330.0",
                                    "31.0",
                                    "32.0"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
      "nextPageToken": "331000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired Output:
[image]

Comment: What is a "row"? Please be precise, what exactly is the output you want?

Comment: Input desired out @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: I'm a fan of flattening in SQL - did you try already? In case you can post your code

Comment: is your question which is better to do the flattening? If your data resides in Snowflake then it's better to use SQL in general

Comment: outside of just creating a table with the dimensions/metrics as names how could  I get each of the dimensions to become column names and the values to fall under the columns, as anticipated in the desired output?